Confusion regarding expressing an $L^{2}$ function with respect to a basis
I am confused about what it means to express an $L^{2}(\Omega)$ function with respect to basis. Suppose we have a basis $\{f_{n}\}$ an orthonormal basis for $L^{2}(\Omega)$, and $\Omega$ has finite measure. This means that, if $h \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ then:
$$h = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\langle f_{n},h\rangle f_{n}$$
and the convergence is with respect to the $L^{2}(\Omega)$ norm. Because this is not pointwise convergence, this does not imply that:
$$h(x) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\langle f_{n},h\rangle f_{n}(x)$$
for every $x\in \Omega$, is that correct?
My question is motivated by the following. Suppose $h$ is an $L^{2}(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ function and let us view it as a multiplication operator. In other words, we have the operator $h: g \mapsto hg$ where $(hg)(x) = h(x)g(x)$. Does it mean that:
$$h(x)g(x) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\langle f_{n},h\rangle f_{n}(x)g(x)$$
or not? And what about for quadratic forms? I mean, can I say something like:
$$\langle w, hg\rangle = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\langle f_{n},h\rangle \langle w, f_{n}g\rangle$$
for $w, g \in L^{2}(\Omega)$?

Your $h$ in the multiplication operator should be in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ not $L^2(\Omega)$ to have $hg \in L^2(\Omega)$, otherwise it is in $L^1(\Omega)$ and not necessarily in $L^2(\Omega)$. But of course it depends which domain and codomain your multiplication operator should have (I think $h: L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega), , g \mapsto hg$ ?).

Yes, true indeed. But assume that $\Omega$ has finite measure. I will edit the post.

Finite measure does not suffice to guarantee $hg \in L^2$: take $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $h(x) = g(x) = 1/\sqrt[4]{x}$ for $x \in (0,1)$. Then $h=g \in L^2((0,1))$ but $hg = h^2 = 1/\sqrt{x} \notin L^2((0,1))$.

@psl2Z you are right. I edited the post again. Thanks!

Convergence in $L^p$ implies pointwise convergence almost everywhere. So, $h(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \langle f_n, h \rangle f_n(x)$ for almost all $x \in \Omega$.

@psl2Z Are you sure $L^p$ convergence implies convergence a.e.?

@SineoftheTime Yeah, ok. I think this is not quite right. It would be right if we would know that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \langle f_n, h \rangle f_n(x)$ would exist a.e.. But this is not clear a priori (only a subsequence converges a.e. in general!).

The answer is no : here is an example. Let $\Omega = [0,\pi]$ and let
$$f_n(x) = \sin(nx)$$
for $n = 1,2,3,...$.
One can show that $f_n$ is a Hilbert basis of $L^2([0,\pi])$ (this can be shown for instance by application of Fourier series with a trick of symmetrization by imparity and periodization).
Let $h(x) = 1$ be the constant function. We have
$$h(x) = \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{2n+1} \quad \text{in } L^2([0,\pi])$$
(this is one of the first series studied by Fourier in his Théorie analytique de la chaleur, by the way! You might know it as the square signal). The convergence is in $L^2([0,\pi])$ but not pointwise: indeed, for $x = 0$ and $x = \pi$, we have $h(x) = 1$ but the series is $0$ (in fact, applying the Dirichlet theorem, one can check that those are the only points where pointwise convergence fails).
In particular, viewing $h$ as a multiplication operator, we do not have
$$ h(x)g(x) = \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{2n+1}g(x)$$
for all $x \in [0,\pi]$.
You might argue that in the previous examples, the series converges pointwise to the right value in the open interval $(0,\pi)$. But you can cook another example where $h$ is piecewise $C^1$, has different left and right limits $h(a^-)$ and $h(a^+)$ at a point $a \in (0,\pi)$. Then the Fourier series will converge to $\frac{h(a^+) + h(a^-)}{2}$ by the Dirichlet theorem. You may choose any other value for $h(a)$ and this gives you another counter-example.
For the last question, it works if $g \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $h \in L^2(\Omega)$. Indeed, in this case, denoting
$$h_N := \sum_{n = 0}^N \langle h,f_n\rangle f_n$$
we have $h_N \to h$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and so
$$\|(h_N - h)g\|^2_{L^2} \leq \|g\|^2_\infty \|h_N - h\|_{L^2}^2 \to 0 $$
as $N \to \infty$. Thus
$h_N g$ converges to $hg$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ as $N \to \infty$, which gives exactly the formula you gave
$$ \langle w,hg\rangle = \lim_{N \to \infty} \langle w,h_Ng\rangle = \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n = 0}^N \langle w,\langle f_n,h\rangle f_n g\rangle = \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n = 0}^N \langle f_n,h \rangle\langle w,f_n g\rangle.$$
For the case where $h \in L^\infty(\Omega) \cap L^2(\Omega)$, I would suspect this does not work but I haven't found a counter-example just yet.

Martin, thanks for your answer. It proves what I believed. However, it made me think. Suppose $h$ is odd. Then we can always write it as a superposition of sines, am I right? I mean, this is the Fourier sine transform. In this case, the convergence is also pointwise.

If $h$ is $2\pi$-periodic and odd on $[-\pi,\pi]$, then its Fourier series "only contains sines" (the Fourier coefficients $a_n$ vanish). But still, it doesn't mean that the Fourier series converges pointwise. It still converges in the $L^2$ norm, but there may be points where $h$ and its Fourier series differ. Again, take $h$ to be discontinuous at $a$ such that  $h(a) \neq \frac{h(a^-) + h(a^+)}{2}$.
